# Exception: The parameters (HtmlService.HtmlOutput) don't match the method signature for Ui.showModalDialog

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, html

Here is my HTML file "Creds.html":

```
<form id="Creds">

  Client ID: <input id="id" type="text" width="45"><br>

  Client Secret: <input id="secret" type="password" width="45"><br>

  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" width="15" onclick="google.script.host.close()"><br> 

</form>
```

Here is the Google Sheets bound Apps Script that is attempting to display it:

```
function setCreds () {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var form_cred = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Creds');

  //var newcreds = ui.showSidebar(form_cred);
  var newcreds = ui.showModalDialog(form_cred);
...
}
```

The `.ShowSidebar` line works when I switch the `//` comment line. However, the `.showModalDialog` line gives the following error:

> Exception: The parameters (HtmlService.HtmlOutput) don't match the
> method signature for Ui.showModalDialog.

Why am I getting this error? What needs to change?

Comment: NOTE: The HTML headers in the HTML file were removed from my HTML code above when I submitted this question, even though I pasted them in. They are there in my file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`showModalDialog` requires a title. [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui?hl=en#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)

Change:  `var newcreds = ui.showModalDialog(form_cred)`

To:
`var newcreds = ui.showModalDialog(form_cred,"title")`

Comment: I should have checked the documentation closer. In my defense, the error generated is not helpful to solving the problem. If nothing else, hopefully this question/answer is an easy to find solution for anyone else having the same problem.

Comment: To be fair, error messages are rarely helpful. But Google is your friend. It's good to remember when anything error occurs that it's almost certain that it has happened to someone else before.